# lazy CocoaAction without memory leak #2 way

Tags: ios, action, rx-swift

`RxSwift` is a powerful feature, but sometimes I shoot myself in the leg.
The problem consist with `Resource count` and object deallocation.
I want to use `lazy var` for `CocoaAction` in View Model. It works fine in this flow:

```
lazy var onCancel: CocoaAction = { [unowned self] _ in
    return CocoaAction {
        return self.coordinator.pop()
    }
}()
```

`Controller` and `View Model` removed from the memory - nice!

The problem appear when I try to use external `self` value (object doesn't remove because action catch strong `reference` to `self`). How to avoid cycle here?

```
lazy var onCancel: CocoaAction = { this in
    return CocoaAction {
        return this.coordinator.pop()
    }
} (self)
```

Comment: Did you try `return CocoaAction { [unowned this] _ in` in your second case?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Yep, I get an error: 'unowned' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '<<error type>>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you need pass a weak reference to the `CocoaAction` to avoid retain cycles. Your first case works because you pass unowned `self` to the first closure which eventually passed to the second closure without increasing retain count. In your second case, you pass `self` to the closure as paramater named `this`, and `this` is passed to the second closure with strong reference. So, you have to pass it weak.

Don't forget to change `TypeOfSelf` to the name of class which you are in. It's required otherwise compiler won't be able to infer the type.

```
lazy var onCancel: CocoaAction = { (this: TypeOfSelf) in
    return CocoaAction { [unowned this] _ in
        return this.coordinator.pop()
    }
}(self)
```

Comment: I have changed TypeOfSelf to my class name and get error:
`Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'CocoaAction' (aka 'Action<(), ()>')` & 
 `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'`

Comment: I agree with your retain cycles theory.

Comment: It's not a big deal because we have a working flow. It's just for expanding understanding.

Comment: @biloshkurskyi.ss Fixed, it was my fault to not put parenthesis around input param

Comment: You are right, I forget about type converting too. Thanks.